# How can I spawn a process (Windows executable) and redirect file read requests for only that process?

Tags: c#, .net

The scenario: I want to write a .NET program that opens X instances of a certain computer game. The computer game (closed-source) is hardcoded to always read a file named "config.ini", which contains some configuration values.

I would like to write code that spawns X instances of said game, and for each instance, trick the game to read a file named "config-1.ini", "config-2.ini", "config-3.ini", and so forth (one separate file per instance), allowing me to make separate configurations per instance of the game.

It's easy enough to launch the game via .NET. Writing the different copies of the .ini file would also be easy enough, just File.Copy(), and let the files stay on the drive until the next time. But how can I trick a certain process to read another file than what it actually requests from the OS?

**Update**: I have found a solution, using the .NET library [EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/remotefilemonitor.html) library and the FileMonitor hooking. It allows me to redirect file I/O within a specific process.

PS: Thanks for the multiple downvotes *rolls eyes*. One always feels welcome at StackOverflow. Not.

Comment: Pretty easy: you **can't**. Imagine you could, how easy would it be to create malware to redirect all files to a chosen one?

Comment: copy `config-1.ini` to `config.ini` and start your process. then continue with other copies

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2007/10/15/using-the-correctfilepaths-shim-to-redirect-files-on-windows-vista/

Comment: @L.B: Alas that's not an option, as changing the options inside the game needs to write to the correctly named config.ini file. For example, when playing instance 2 of the game, changing the options inside the game must be written to the "config-2.ini" file.

Also, CamiloTerevinto , you're wrong, because I have an existing program (but no source code) that does precisely this, so it is possible somehow. I'm trying to replicate the behavior. I have checked using Process Monitor that the program does not simply watch the base config.ini file and copy it to the relevant file name either.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, using the .NET library EasyHook library and the FileMonitor hooking. It allows me to redirect file I/O within a specific process. Here is the sample I used, with minor modifications:

https://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/remotefilemonitor.html

PS: Thanks for the multiple downvotes *rolls eyes*. One always feels welcome at StackOverflow. Not.